# Post comments to someones profile post or page post or group post using facebook javascript sdk

Tags: javascript, facebook, sdk

I want to post comments to someone's Facebook profile post or page post or group post using the `Facebook Javascript SDK` with an access token and `Graph API`.

I can generate an application access token from a current logged in user with `publish_stream` permission. How do I use the Javascript SDK call using `post id` so that a user can comment from outside Facebook, that is from my site where all page/profile/group posts are shown?

I tried the PHP SDK, but is not working on the server site.

Comment: @Fred A lot of your edits are showing up in the edit queue at the moment, and they're almost all far too minor. Please don't keep suggesting edits unless they address substantial issues in the question.

Comment: @NicholasWilson Sorry, just trying to make things better on SO and doing my part. It's the "book editor" in me. ;-)

Answer (score 1):

Assuming user already logged in and access token has publish_stream permissions, you should call

```
FB.api('/'+ _POST_ID_HERE_ +'/comments', 'POST', { message:"Your comment text" },
       function(response)
       {
            if (response && !response.error && response.id)
            {
                 alert('New comment id = '+response.id);
            }
       });
```

Comment: i already did this way -                                                                        FB.api('508859247/comments?message=metedddst44&access_token=BAA94UZAlk9QG2VKIoThFwyEZD', 'post', function(response) {
  if (!response || response.error) {
    alert('Error occured');
  } else {
    alert('comment added to the post');
  }
}); but i am getting "Error occured" where post id is of another user's profile post and is public.i tried your way but same problem.

Comment: You can add response.error to your alert message and see what's wrong with the post. Otherwise it should work as is.

Comment: i did add response.error but not shows anything              later i generated a access token by this link http://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer giving all permission and tried with that token then its working so to comment on a profile post i have to generate token with some other permissions(not only publish_stream permission) can anyone help what specific permission needed?

Comment: You could try to generate access token with only "publish_stream" permission in Graph Explorer and see if it will work. If not, add permissions one by one and see if it helps. Probably you should also add "read_stream" permission, but I didn't see any mention of that in FB's documentation.

Answer (score 0):

function Comment_Clicked(pid)
{
    FB.init({
          appId   : '472562079456084',
          status  : true, // check login status
          //channelUrl : '//WWW.YOUR_DOMAIN.COM/channel.html', // Channel File
          cookie  : true, // enable cookies to allow the server to access the session
          xfbml   : true // parse XFBML
          //oauth:true
        });

```
    FB.login(function(response) {
        if (response.status=='connected') {
            if (response.authResponse.accessToken) {
                var token = response.authResponse.accessToken;      

                FB.api('/'+pid+'/comments?access_token='+token+'', 'POST',{ message:'test' }, function(response) {
                  if (!response || response.error) {
                    ms_js("#msfb-error-comlike").text("Errors you may not have permissions ");
                  } else {
                    ms_js("#msfb-error-comlike").text("Post success");
                  }
                });
                //window.location = "<? echo $absolute_url; ?>&temptoken="+ token +"";
            } else {
                // user is logged in, but did not grant any permissions
                alert('You can create an access token only for your own profiles and pages.');
            }
        } else {
            // user is not logged in
            alert('To use fb.wall you have to create an access token.');
        }
    }, {scope:'read_stream,publish_stream'}); //exclude publish_stream,publish_actions
```

}

this my complete function which does the comment.here i am generating a access token by app id.is it right? by a app access token a user can comment on another page,profile post instead of his page or profile post?! things go ok so is using. @Const actually publish_stream permission works for another user performing comment to another user profile post which i tested.but for the user for which problem is still problem, dont know why!.generating token giving all permissions using javascript sdk in my local site not working but works when i generate here - developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer....